# JAVA populate a POJO void method vs methods which return fields which is better?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-management, coding-style, pojo

JAVA 1.8

What is the most readable/efficient way to populate a class "**Customer**" from another class "**Person**"?

**AddressInfo, ContactPreferences** and **AuthorizationRoles** are all complex POJOS with multiple fields and we need to make additional DB calls and service calls.

```
public Customer getCustomerFromPerson(Person per) {
Customer cust = new Customer();
 populateAddressInfo(cust, per);
 populateContactPreferences(cust, per);
 populateAuthorizationRoles(cust, per);
 ...
 return cust;
}
```

## vs

```
public Customer getCustomerFromPerson(Person per) {
Customer cust = new Customer();
 cust.setAddressInfo(getAddressInfoFromPerson(per));
 cust.setContactInfo(getContactPreferencesForCust(cust, per));
 cust.setAuthRoles(getAuthorizationRoles(per));
 ...
 return cust;
}
```

## Note:

The Customer.AddressInfo != Person.AddressInfo. They are very little mapping and we pull additional data from DB/Soap to get complete Customer.Addressinfo
    cust.getAddressInfo.setIsBillingAddress(**Webservicecall(per.getAddressInfo)**);

Comment: Why does your person not have getters, such as person.GetAddressInfo ?

Comment: The way you have explained is having setters with different name until you return a new customer with every call of  populate*() . I would think keeping them as setters makes it more readable.

Comment: The address info in person the the complete address info needed for customer i.e.  cust.getAddressInfo != per.getAddressInfo. Customer.AddressInfo needs more info, type conversion and maybe additional service call in addition to all the data in Person.Addressinfo

Comment: You can implement a **builder pattern** [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at Apache `BeanUtils.copyProperties`.

```
public static void copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)
           throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
```

It might do what you want a lot quicker, although there can be a penalty with type safety and performance.

Link: [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: There is very little one to one mapping with the Customer and Person, so this is not a good fit.  Customer needs an lot of additional data to be complete-thanks